# Why do the same code behave differently in the category.php and page.php and how can this be circumvented?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please tell me how to solve the problem.
I post in a separate category post, which scored more than 100 views. But if I put it in the category.php, then the last 20-30 posts are clipped and not output. And if the same code is copied into the page.php, then everything is displayed. Obviously, the built-in behavior of the category hinders. How can I fix this?
The post output code is lower.

```
<?php get_template_part('header/header', 'header'); ?>
<?php
$pagedCat = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$argsForLast = array(
'orderby'     => 'date',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
        'count_views' => array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
            'value'   => '100',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    ),
$argsAllPosts = get_posts($argsForLast);
$argsMain = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'count_views' => array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
            'value'   => '100',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    ),
));



$lastPostId = $argsAllPosts[0]->ID;


$argsOther = new WP_Query(array(
    'paged' => $pagedCat,
    'post_type' =>  'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'count_views' => array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
            'value'   => '110',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in' => array($lastPostId)
));
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = $argsOther;
?>
```

And search and output of posts

```
 <?php if ( $argsOther -> have_posts() ) :?>
   <section class="other-posts-wrap scroll-wrap">
   <?php 
    while ( $argsOther -> have_posts() ) : $argsOther -> the_post();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset data before Execute another query

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

OR

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Does not help
and why then in the page.php without the reset works?